# WPF: after add WPF Toolkit DLL

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

After add rrr DLL i am looking at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co) tutorial.
Do i need to add some reference in my `XAML` in order to find `chartingToolkit:Chart` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the opening `Window` tag, the tutorial's code imports the namespace your are talking about. Do you have the following XAML in your opening `Window` tag?

`xmlns:chartingToolkit=
    "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
    assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"`

If you are unfamiliar with referencing CLR namespaces from XAML, I strongly recommend reading this [MSDN introduction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546(v=vs.90).aspx) on the topic.